# How to query every last 15 mins data in mongo database

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongoid

In my collection  conn_time field have value stored like ISODate("2013-06-11T07:30:02.001Z").i need a query to get last 15 mins of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract the 15 minutes from current date in the way given below:
These are the command you can run on mongodb console.

```
var endDate=new Date()
var startDate=new Date(endDate-15*60*1000)
```

and Now, you can query using startDate and endDate like:

```
db.conn_time.find({created_date_time:{$gte:startDate,$lt:endDate}})
```

**Updating the answer**

Selecting ids of objects for last 15 min or 1 hour.

```
var endDate=new Date()
var startDate=new Date(endDate-15*60*1000)

var endDate1Hour=new Date()
var startDate1Hour = new Date(endDate1Hour-60*60*1000)
```

and Now, you can query using startDate and endDate like:

```
db.conn_time.find({$or:[{created_date_time:{$gte:startDate,$lt:endDate}},{created_date_time:{$gte:startDate1Hour,$lt:endDate1Hour}}],{_id:1})
```

Hope that helps!!!

Thanks

Comment: Thanks! Is there anyway to get object ids created in last 15 mins or 1 hour